# Show that there exists a step function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f:[a,b] \rightarrow X$ is a continuous map. By an argument based on uniform continuity, show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a step-function $u: [a,b] \rightarrow X$ such that for all $x \in [a,b]$, $||f(x)-u(x)||<\epsilon$.

Okay, so I have looked back to the uniform continuity-definition, but I still can't see how I can connect that definition with the exercise...
Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give some hints, but please comment if you would like more clarification:

- Any continuous function on a compact space is uniformly continuous. The bounded closed interval $[a,b]$ is compact, by Heine-Borel. Therefore, your $f$ is uniformly continuous.
- The definition of uniformly continuity tells you that, whatever positive $\epsilon $ you're given, it's possible to find a sufficiently small positive $\delta $ that
  $$ | x_1 - x_2 | < \delta \implies | f(x_1) - f(x_2) | < \epsilon. $$

Now imagine a step function $u$, with steps of width less than $\delta$. We set the value of $u$ on a given step to be equal to the value of $f$ at the middle of the step. Can you see that this $u$ obeys $|u(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$?

Edit: Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I understand what u say. Now i got a clue. I'm thinking about something like $(b-a)/n <\delta $ at the moment (large n). hmm...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the right idea! Can you see that, no matter how small $\delta$ is, you can always find an $n$ large enough that $(b - a)/ n < \delta$?

Comment: By the way, when you've finished this, I suggest you think about what goes wrong if the domain is not a closed interval: for example, consider $f(x) = \tan x$ defined on $[0, \pi / 2)$. This $f$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous. By drawing a similar graph to the one that I drew, can you see why this strategy would not work for $f(x) = \tan x$ on $[0, \pi / 2)$?

Comment: It won't work because $tan(x)$ tends to infinity when $x \rightarrow \pi/2$... There exist no supremum on this point? Am I on right track?

Comment: Back to the question: What's next to show? How to find the $u$?

Comment: $u(x_i)$ changes value for every $2\delta$

Comment: Hi, we don't need to "find" $u$, because we are _defining_ $u(x)$ to be the value of $f$ at the centre of the step. For example, if $x \in [a + k(b-a)/n, a + (k+1)(b-a)/n)$, where $k$ is an integer between $0$ and $n-1$, then $u(x) = f(a + (k + \tfrac 1 2)(b-a)/n)$. It looks ugly when written down, which is why it's better to explain using words/pictures.

Comment: What we need to show is that, for any $x$, $|u(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I need a little bit more help... :/

Comment: And do you mean $|u(x)-f(x)|<\delta$

Comment: No, I do mean $|u(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. Given $x$, let $x_{\rm centre}$ be the centre of the step that $x$ is in. Can you see that $| x_{\rm centre} - x | < \delta$? So what does this tell you?

Comment: This implies that $|u(x_{centre})-f(x)|<\epsilon$ ...

Comment: It implies that $|f(x_{\rm centre}) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. Do you agree? Now, how is $u(x)$ defined?

Comment: I have no idea now :(

Comment: Well, $u(x)$ is _defined_ as $u(x) = f(x_{\rm centre})$! So $|u(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$. And that is exactly what you want to show.

Comment: Oh my days, thats what I excatly thought about after I did last comment! I will try to find a conclusion now.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor\leq1$. Using this fact, 
$$u(x)=\epsilon\cdot\lfloor \frac{f(x)}{\epsilon}\rfloor$$